# Subscribe to events usign geth websocket

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, events, websocket

I'm trying to subscribe to geth using the websocket api. First step was to start geth:

```
geth --ws --wsport=8456 --wsorigins="*" --fast --cache=512 --rpcport=8455 --rpc --rpcapi="personal,eth,network"
```

Then I tried to connect to it using websockets from python:

```
from websockets import connect
import asyncio

async def get_event():
    async with connect("ws://localhost:8456") as ws:
        await ws.send(json.dumps({"id": 1, "method": "eth_subscribe", "params": ["newPendingTransactions"]}))
        subscription_response = await ws.recv()
        while True:
            try:
                message = await asyncio.wait_for(ws.recv(), timeout=60)
                pass
            except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                # No data in 20 seconds, check the connection.
                try:
                    pong_waiter = await ws.ping()
                    await asyncio.wait_for(pong_waiter, timeout=10)
                except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                    # No response to ping in 10 seconds, disconnect.
                    logger.critical("socket timeout")
                    break
            else:
                pprint(message)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    while True:
        loop.run_until_complete(get_event())
```

I'm getting subscription response:
'{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"result":"0xde19c48fe52cd12207f807f330630e2b"}'

But not receiving any messages after that and running in the TimeoutError. Any idea what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

At first glance it appears you are not enabling any of the available --wsapi methods (personal, admin, eth, web3). You are enabling them on --rpcapi. That could be what is causing the time out. Does geth time out, or your application?